# how to modify admin page to add extra columns?

Tags: python, django

can anybody explain how to add more columns in django admin page.
and how the meta class works, how it adds the columns from list

```
class SignUpAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): # what is ModelAdmin class 

  list_display = ['__unicode__','timestamp'] # columns created in models file
  class Meta:
    model = SignUp     # SignUp class created as Model class in model.py file
admin.site.register(Signenter code hereUp, SignIpAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use Meta class in your admin class. when you want to add database columns to your admin UI just pass them in your `list_display=['title', 'timestamp',]` array